# Hide Image in Custom ListView In Android

Tags: android, listview

I am designing a Android Application For A Social Networking Site. 
i want to display the posts which users friend Posted, 
There can be 2 types of post, a photo post or a text only post, 
i created a Custom listview which gets the data in JSON format. the structure of Custom List view is

Friend Name  (textView )
Posted Picture  (ImageView ) 
Posted Date & Time

Now The Issue is , i am not able to hide the Imageview Control For the Text only post as there is no need of image here.

when i try to hide the image for textonly posts, all the images for all the posts gets invisible.

Please help me to achieve this.

Here Is The Code

```
@Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View itemView = convertView;
            if ( itemView == null)
            {
                itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.postlistview, parent,false);
            }
            Posts CurrentPost = myPosts.get(position);
            // myPosts Is the List Of Posts, (Usermane, Posttext, PostImage, IsPhotoPost)

            //Retrieving The User Name
            TextView userName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_username);
            userName.setText(CurrentPost.getUserName());

            // Retrieving Whether the Post Is TextOnly Or Photo Post and Photo AssignMent 
            ImageView imgView =(ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_photo);
            if ( CurrentPost.IsPhotoPost() ) // If True
                {
                    URL url = null;
                    Bitmap bmp = null;
                    try {
                        url = new URL(CurrentPost.getPostPhoto());
                        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

                    }catch (IOException e) {

                    }
                    imgView.setImageBitmap(bmp); 
                }
            else
            {
                imgView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            } 
}
```

When I execute it, all the post pictures gets invisible

Comment: Post the code for your adapter(or the relevant code that you're using).

Comment: i edited the question and placed the code as well, please have a look n give me solution if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `ImageView` to visible when you want to display items otherwise it will always stay invisible:

```
ImageView imgView =(ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_photo);
if ( CurrentPost.IsPhotoPost() ) // If True
    {
        URL url = null;
        Bitmap bmp = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(CurrentPost.getPostPhoto());
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

        }catch (IOException e) {

        }
        imgView.setImageBitmap(bmp); 
        imgView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
else
{
    imgView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```